# If he doesn't do his work, he will/would get fired

Tags: modal-verbs

Consider these *first conditional* sentences, please:

1. If he doesn't do his work, he **will** get fired. (his boss will fire him)
2. If he doesn't do his work, he **would** get fired. (his boss would fire him)

(1) and (2) do not refer to any particular time in the future, but any time after "he" has started the job. Are they both correct/natural? If so, Is there any difference between "will" and "would" here?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_mood#English - the first sentence is "predictive/conditional I", and the second *would* be "counterfactual/conditional II" if you change*d* "doesn't" to "didn't", as [counterfactual sentences are written in "fake" past tense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterfactual_conditional#Fake_tense)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The first sentence is correct and natural, but the second is incorrect, though it may often be used. The meanings of the two are different. The first is definite - if A then B. It sounds even as though "he" is not doing the work and is therefore likely to be fired. The second should, as stated in Kate Bunting's comment below, be "If he didn't do his work he would be fired". This could be hypothetical, for example as part of a discussion of HR policies.

Comment: I dispute that (2) is 'correct and natural'.  It should be "If he **didn't** do his work (a hypothetical situation), he **would** get fired."

Comment: It seemed  correct and natural to me yesterday, but after reading your comment it no longer does. I will correct my answer.